# Create an article that can only be accessed by email link?

Tags: email, joomla, hyperlink, restriction

case: I have this website and I want to add more subscribers to the newsletter while still maintaining a good traffic on my website. Therefore, I want to have competitions and special offers exclusively for newsletter subscribers BUT! I want them to go from the newsletter to the site to participate in the contest.

As I want this to be an exclusive thing for the newsletter subscribers, I don't want a URL that is accessible simply by typing it in (e.g. www.my-site.com/competition1). Is it possible to make a link that creates a unique URL when it is clicked (e.g. www.my-site.com/competition1?2281990578345) or something?

Please forgive me if this sounds far out and correct me if i am missing something totally obvious here. I hope this can be done in some way though.

Best, Astrid :-)

Comment: What you could do is, create a hidden menu, then create a menu item linking to that article

Comment: @Lodder That's probably the best way to go, but subscribers will be able to re-distribute :(

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos - ah yes you make a good point. The only problem is that in life, anything is redistributable, such as music, films etc, so I'm not too sure of a completely safe bet on this :/

Comment: If it's a burn-URL, meaning that it won't work unless you supply a unique ID (from a pre-defined list) each time, then it is possible, but legit users may lose access with just refreshing the link.

Comment: Hi, this sounds ok interesting - I shall research on the topic of burn-URLs :-) Maybe that is the answer

Comment: I just came up with the term - I'm not sure if that even exists as a functionality anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do this, but I have created a plugin for my [NS Pro newsletter extension](http://mavrosxristoforos.com/joomla-extensions/commercial/nspro), which lets users to filter content if the logged-in user's email exists in the subscriber database.

It has two drawbacks: It requires that the users are logged-in with the same email that they subscribed, and it isn't yet available for Joomla 3.

Comment: It sounds kind of cool, but I don't work with user registration - I will, however, consider that option. I use MailChimp so I am not sure I can just implement a plugin. --- I guess what I am looking for is something in the link syntax that triggers the generation of a unique ID which appends to the link and which it cannot work without, kind of when you have a unique check-out url in a webshop. I don't know too much about these things, as mentioned, it just occurred to me that this might be the way to go if I wanted people to subscribe to the newsletter :-)

Comment: Alright Aztrid, but as we discussed with Lodder - you simply cannot stop susbcribers from re-distributing.

Comment: Okay. So, my idea is not possible. Thank you for your time and effort though :-)